# Querying a web service via WDSL

Tags: 7, nodes, search, services

I am thinking about creating a search engine frontend for a special use case using Drupal 7. There are some modules in the module directory, and questions like [Consume SOAP web service in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580120/consume-soap-web-service-in-drupal-7) on SO, but I still am confused.

How is the mapping from external datasets to dynamic Drupal nodes done? For every dataset I retrieve through my service's WSDL interface, I'll need to create a node, a block or anything displayable in Drupal.

Is this even possible within the scope of Drupal's framework?

Answer (score 1):

Yup its possible, PHP is specifically a web based language -- which Drupal is built upon.

For a REST based consuming service client for instance look at the [Guzzle](http://drupal.org/project/guzzle) drupal community project. There is also the [Services Client](http://drupal.org/project/services_client) drupal community module to consume remote web services and uses UUIDs to map/sync fetched data. Your mileage may vary but all the pieces exist within Drupal and PHP. For instance even D7's core [drupal_http_request](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request) can be used to craft your own HTTP requests, or your underlying PHP's installation CuRL library if you find drupals http function hindered by defaults.

There is also an [issue and related sandbox project to add SOAP support to the Feeds](http://drupal.org/node/833558) drupal community module.

You say SOAP but thats only 1 piece of what can go over the wire. I've had to consume WS-* + SOAP based APIs from Drupal/PHP and I ended up creating XML by hand with CuRL to do it all. There are also libraries such as:

http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/

or this library to extend php5 ext/SOAP:

https://code.google.com/p/wse-php/

Ultimately understanding the remote API specs, and inter-operating with them from Drupal is on you the developer.

Comment: Thanks for the links and comments you provided. However, my core question was about the representation of dynamic data in the Drupal framework -- how to dynamically create nodes / blocks from an incoming result set.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the mapping from external datasets to dynamic Drupal nodes
>   done?

Effectively, it's done manually. You can use PHP5's [SOAP client](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), or a third party one, and write your custom integration. There's no generalized module for this task, because each API is different.

The answer you linked to on SO shows the basics.